# Entry.get() not returning full user entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following function:

```
def some_search(event):
    print userSearch.get()
```

And I've set the function to run whenever the user types in the entry field using the below code:

```
userSearch.bind("<Key>", some_search)
```

My problem is that `userSearch.get()` doesn't return what's actually in the entry field.

For example, if `"test"` is in the entry field, the function prints `"tes"`.

If `"Hello World"` is in the entry field, the function prints `"Hello Worl"`.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm fairly new to programming, I suspect the answer will be a simple one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event occurs before the keypress has affected the entry. You will need to take the `char` and `keysym` attributes of the event object and apply them to the entry contents.

Comment: Could you help me understand exactly how I'd go about doing this? I'm struggling to work it out myself.

Comment: Actually I worked it out, your solution works.  Thanks, Ignacio!

Answer (score 0):

Change the binding method from `"<Key>"` to `"<KeyRelease>"`